# How do you prevent monster spawn but not animals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Creepers spawn all over my well-lit island. So do animals. Can I make creepers not spawn but the animals do?

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the light level of your island should prevent hostile mob spawns while not hindering passive animal spawns.  Hostile mobs only spawn if the light level is below 7; remember that a torch provides level 14 light and this decreases by one for every block away from the torch.

As for why creepers are still spawning, the obvious answer is that your island is not as well-lit as you thought.  Perhaps there is a cave somewhere you overlooked, or a spot where 2 torches are a couple blocks too far apart.

Answer (score 2):

Just turning the difficulty to peaceful will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the console, you can try is:

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

This will keep spawning mobs, including the creepers, however when they explode, they won't destroy the island. This won't stop them from spawning, but it will stop the destruction of the blocks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP asked for a solution with which monsters don't spawn, **but animals do**.

Comment: @Fabian the last time I checked, this was how the command was meant to work. But it seems that is no longer the case.